# Problems converting Matlab code into Python

Tags: python, matlab

Hello i would like to convert two piece of matlab code in python.

I try to do:

```
~isnan(matr(:,2)) into not(isnan(matr[:,1]))
```

but it returns this error:

```
not(isnan(matr[:,1]))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and the second one is:

```
[a,b] = min(d);
```

I try to do:

```
a,b = d.min(0)
```

but it returns this error:

```
a,b = d.min(0)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Many thanks for the support

Comment: min returns the smallest element in an array and you are trying to get two values out. If d is a list then all you need to get the smallest element is `a=min(d)`

Comment: Are you using nested lists or tuples in python, or using a class from numpy?

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1, you are not using the right indexing syntax:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> c = ( (1,2) , (3, 4))
>>> x = isnan(c[:][1])
>>> x[0]
False
>>> x[1]
False
```

For problem 2:

```
>>> d = [[1,2],[3,4]]   
>>> a,b=min(d)          
>>> a                   
1                       
>>> b                   
2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems for 1.  First, `not` is not a function, it is an operator, so you wouldn't do `not(foo)`, you would do `not foo`.  `not(foo)` works, but that is because it is using `(...)` for grouping, which in your case doesn't do anything.

The bigger problem, though, is that operators like `not`, `and`, and `or` are short-circuit operations (they stop after the first failure), which doesn't work properly with numpy arrays.  You need to use the bitwise operator `~`, such as `~isnan(matr[:,1])`

For the second problem, I take it you are trying to do the MATLAB equivalent of getting the minimum and the index of the minimum?  In numpy, these are two different operations, `min` and `argmin`, respectively.  Python doesn't support changing the behavior of a function based on its output arguments (at least not in any simple manner).